# iframe not active unless receives user interaction

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-domain, mobile-safari

I've been working on a requirement that involves a website fetching/manipulating data stored on a different domain. There didn't seem a way except for enabling CORS on the other server to allow me to get and modify data from a different domain. However, that caused some issues with Office 365 apps and I had to take a different approach.

The approach is to use `postMessage` to talk to a hidden `iframe` (not a good approach, but I was insisted to use it) on the page that is running on the target domain. The source page posts message along with information about the REST call to the hidden `iframe` which makes a requests on behalf of the parent page and uses `postMessage` to return back the results.

Everything works fine except for when the website is being used on an iPhone. Turned out placing `alert` calls in the script running inside the target `iframe` makes it to work but removing the `alert` calls sort of disables the target `iframe` from making those cross-origin network calls.

My theory is that it is due to the security of mobile Safari that in order to make cross-origin calls from an `iframe` running on a different domain, the user needs to provide their consent by interacting at least once with the embedded `iframe`. Does that sound correct?

Comment: Sounds plausible. If you have a dummy button in the iframe page, having the user click it would give you the same result as the alert if this is correct.

Comment: You could use a proxy on your domain to get the data and avoid CORS and iframe issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment by [diodeus-james-macfarlane](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12579/diodeus-james-macfarlane) is the closest that we could go but the iframe being hidden, there was no way we could have placed a control for the user to interact with, even if that was only for it to work.

To my surprise, turning off a setting on the SharePoint site made it work. The setting was around mobile view compatibility and without that, the iframe is able to make HTTP requests, send and receive messages to and from the parent webpage.